# when all I get is EOF from a net.TCPConn, how do I know if the connection has been dropped?

Tags: go, tcp, ftp

The godocs say:

"EOF is the error returned by Read when no more input is available. Functions should return EOF only to signal a graceful end of input. If the EOF occurs unexpectedly in a structured data stream, the appropriate error is either ErrUnexpectedEOF or some other error giving more detail."

and in my program I would `love` love to get ErrUnexpectedEOF, but I don't. I always get just EOF even when the client terminates in the middle of sending a file.

so, i'm stuck. Successful files that transfer 100% of the way thru send EOF at end. And files that quit 50% thru with error also send EOF as the error. I do not know the total size of the file before the transfer.

Is there any more information I could get from the net.TCPConn to know was this a full file or not?

Comment: This is how TCP works. You need some higher level protocol to determine if the connection closed early.

Comment: @JimB is right. TCP is a "streaming" protocol that streams bytes, not a packet/block based protocol.

Comment: Well, how does Go know the EOF is unexpected?

Answer (score 1):

TCP is a streaming protocol; a stream of bytes. That's why file transfer protocols invented/implemented upon TCP, like FTP (File Transfer Protocol).

But (not recommended/thought experiment) if you can send your files in chunks that does not contain a certain character/byte (like base64 + \n as that certain character), then you can use that certain character as delimiter.

Now if we handle our connections using a function similar to this:

```
func (srv *Server) handler(conn net.Conn) {
    //...

    defer srv.closeConnection(conn, nil)

    reader := bufio.NewReader(conn)
    writer := bufio.NewWriter(conn)

    //...

    conn.SetDeadline(time.Now().Add(conf.ClientTimeout))

    for {
        select {
        case <-conf.QuitSignal:
            return
        default:
            line, err := reader.ReadBytes('\n')
            if err != nil {
                return
            }

            //...
        }

        conn.SetDeadline(time.Now().Add(conf.ClientTimeout))
    }
}

func (srv *Server) closeConnection(conn net.Conn, err error) {
    conn.Close()
    //...
}
```

From the documentation of `Reader.ReadBytes` we read *ReadBytes returns err != nil **if and only if** the returned data does not end in delimiter*. This way we can recognize a broken chunk.